# Lua-cURL: https get into string

Tags: lua

I would like to fetch the body of an HTTPS response into a Lua variable using lcURL. Here is what I have so far, but it does not work:

```
local cURL = require("lcurl");

function x(str)
    print(x)
end

curl = cURL.easy{url='https://devrant.com', writefunction=x}:perform():close()
```

I have found lots of examples of how to write them into a file, but not into a variable.

My output is:

```
function: 0x5594bfd310f0
function: 0x5594bfd310f0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I swear I'm not an idiot, but my behavior in this post is clear evidence otherwise. I'm printing `x`. FML. The solution is to print `str`

Comment: I use `t={} handle:setopt_writefunction(table.insert, t) handle:perform() result = table.concat(t)`